# How do I attach wires to this socket

Tags: wiring, lamp

I have a lamp I want to connect to my wiring, but I can't figure out how the wires should be attached. Below you can see the only page in the instruction manual following the lamp which deals with this, as well as the lamp socket.

Can someone give me a pointer on how to attach the wires please?

My location is Norway, if it matters.

[image]

[image]

[image]

The wires go in here somehow?

[image]

Comment: Flos is a Norwegian manufacturer of lamps, who sells nationwide. They look legit to me, I did a fake check because the wiring method seemed a bit dodgy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that the red arrows are pointing at the tabs that actuate the spring clips in the holes on either side of them.

Depress the spring clips  by inserting a small flat blade screwdriver into the opening and press down,  then insert wire into hole, release spring clip and the tension should keep the wires snug.

I believe that there a two holes on each side so you can send another set of wires out to daisy chain  another fixture.

Comment: Oh, that makes way more sense. I couldn't figure out how I would prevent them from pulling out. I'll see if I can give this a go tomorrow, and if it seems to work I'll mark this as a solution :-)